# AMP page not working in Next js 13 app directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

My code is working fine on the development server but it's failing while build generation.

**Error: `export const config` in C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\apps\bike_junction\app/web-stories/[slug]/page.jsx is deprecated. Please change `runtime` property to segment export config. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config
at getPageStaticInfo (C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\build\analysis\get-page-static-info.js:378:27)
at async getStaticInfoIncludingLayouts (C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\build\entries.js:104:28)
at async C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\build\entries.js:385:32
at async Promise.all (index 72)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async createEntrypoints (C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\build\entries.js:516:5)
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:103:20)
at async webpackBuildImpl (C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-build\impl.js:102:25)
at async webpackBuild (C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-build\index.js:137:16)
at async C:\Users\nitindutta_tractorju\Desktop\website-builder-monorepo\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.16_@babel+core@7.22.8_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:595:123

- info Creating an optimized production build **
  I am using next *14.3.16* currently.
  Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
import Script from "next/script";
import React from "react";
import { getStories } from "../../../apis";
export const config = { amp: "true" };

const AmpWebStory = async (props) => {

  const data = await getStories(props?.params?.slug);

  const stories = data?.data?.[0]?.attributes?.stories??[];

  return (
    <html amp>
      <head>
        <Script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></Script>
        <Script
          async
          key="amp-story"
          custom-element="amp-story"
          src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-1.0.js"
        />
      </head>

      <amp-story
        standalone=""
        title="Stories in AMP - Hello World"
        publisher="AMP Project"
      >
    { stories.map((item, index)=>{
      const isLast = index === stories.length - 1;
      return(
        <amp-story-page id={`page-${item.id}`} auto-advance-after="4s" key={item.id}>
        <amp-story-grid-layer
          template="fill"
          animate-in-delay="0.4s"
        >
          <amp-img
            src={item?.image?.data?.attributes?.url}
            width="720"
            height="1280"
            layout="responsive"
          ></amp-img>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" animate-in="fly-in-left">
          <div className="ampStory_title">
          {item.title? <h1>{item.title}</h1>: null}
        { item.story? <p>{item.story}</p>: null}
          </div>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>

         { isLast? <amp-story-cta-layer>
            <a href="#" class="click-btn">Click here...</a>
          </amp-story-cta-layer>:null}

      </amp-story-page>
      )
    })    
   
    }
        

        <amp-story-bookend
          src="https://amp.dev/static/samples/json/bookend.json"
          layout="nodisplay"
        ></amp-story-bookend>
      </amp-story>
    </html>
  );
};

export default AmpWebStory;
```

Comment: Resolved it using a GET API route which returns an amp html . And it worked.